# Django can't find the static files

Tags: django

I just started a new project and currently Django can't find the static files. I'm using Django==2.2.6

The static files are located in an app called "website". This is the file structure.

https://i.imgur.com/AnPACop.png

This is from the settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This is how i include the static file:

```
{% static 'css/style.css' %}
```

The URL to the static file seems correct:

```
<link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

EDIT: its NOT correct. But this works:

```
<link href="/static/core/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 3):

Make your file structure like the following one:

```
ProjectFolderName
   static
      - css
      - js
   template
   website
   projectfoldername
   migrations
```

Put your static folder in your project folder. Then make these changes to your `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

Then run this command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

You static file will be copied to New file created by django as assets.
and add to your HTML

```
{% load static %}
```

Comment: I want to put the static files for the website in the website-app. I know I've managed to get that working before.

Is there any need to collectstatic in dev? I'm just using Django locally now.

Comment: It's fine, just you have to Deal with path. Regarding collectstatic, if you make any changes to Your css and js in between then sometime changes don't reflect even in dev. so,better run this command.

Comment: Please read the updated question. It's only the URL to the file that's incorrect.

Comment: change it to ```<link href="/static/core/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">```  You could have used ```<link href="{% static 'path' %} rel = "stylesheet">```  when your static folder is inside projectfolder not in app.

Comment: Yes. I know. But how do I change it? It's not hardcoded. See the question.

Comment: This is how i include the CSS: <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 1):

This is the URL that the browser will find your static files. It won't let Django know in which folder to find them inside your project root (`BASE_DIR)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Try using this instead to specify the directory you are storing the statics

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'website/static'),)
```

Also, make sure you are loading the statics in your template with the following template tag

```
{% load static %}
```

### Update

The path to the CSS is also wrong on the `html` you should change it to:

```
<link href="/static/core/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The STATICFILES_DIRS didn't do the trick though. I use {% load static %}, the URL to the file seems correct: /static/css/style.css

Comment: I just saw that the path to CSS on `html` is also wrong check my updated answer

Comment: I've updated my question a bit regarding the include. :) Thanks for the help, again!

Comment: btw. http://localhost/static/core/css/style.css works, just fine

Comment: nice to hear it is solved! If you could also accept my solution!

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. The problem was the file structure. For some reason the static files was in a core-folder.
https://i.imgur.com/AnPACop.png

When i put the files directly in "static" it started working.

Answer (score 0):

My english is not perfect, sorry in advance.

I'm in Django 3 and I had the same problem. This how I find what's wrong, with the help of everyone up me. Just consider this post like a note for me.

I do :

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

At this moment I read the last line of the output. It was looking in a file that did'nt exist. I copied the path. Go in terminal and :

```
cd path/copied/before/static/base.css
```

File not found. At this moment I know what to do. Just follow the path and create the folder I need.

I know it's not a good practise but it's can help beginner.